# Vertical scrollbar overlaps profile page

Tags: bug, design, scrolling

I have noticed, on my new laptop, that the vertical scroll bar is overlapping information on the user page (MSO, SO, and MSE tested so far) like this:

[image]

This is, though not critical, an annoying, and also present on profile view.

I have not experienced this before, so it may be related to my new system*, but it is still a problem and may be experienced by other users as well.

---

<sub><sub>* Google Chrome on Windows 7 Pro, 64 bit Display res: 1024x768</sub></sub>

Comment: Isn't this just a function of the page being sidescrolling?

Comment: @Catija I posted this a few days ago, strange things seem to have happened?! That was before the new horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: As part of the updates to the page layout, we're moving to a responsive design. We haven't gotten to that on our profile pages because they're pretty complex to make flexible, so on narrower screen widths, they will side scroll instead of adjusting. If that's your browser's scrollbar and not a secondary scroll bar (which would be a bug), then it should appear above the content on the page.

Comment: @Catija When I thought I posted this, there was no/non-functional horizontal scrollbar, and the vertical one overlapped the content. As it is currently, on the same laptop, there is both a horizontal scroll bar at the bottom, and a horizontal one on the left, and no overlap of content when scrolled furthest to the left.

Comment: Hmmm... The horizontal scrollbar shouldn't be new. I've been getting it for a few months, so I'm not sure what happened a couple of days ago or why this post didn't get posted until right now. Looks like all is well, though, so ... yay! :D

Comment: I had a horizontal scrollbar for years everywhere on SE, including profile pages.  Responsive design removes it, but not all pages have been made responsive even on sites that have the new responsive design.